# How to draw summary chart in excel

Tags: excel

Given the data:

```
Time taken (ms)
100
120
130
131
132
145
144
200
250
255
```

How to draw a line chart in which the y axis is the count, and the x axis is intervals of 20 of Time Taken eg 0, 20, 40, 60, etc?

Comment: Do you mean a histogram ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Mock up the desired result manually and explain in context.

Comment: @TimWilliams the op is asking for a line chart. a histogram is typically a column chart, but then, why not plot it as a line ....

Comment: @teylyn - you're right: I missed the "line" part.

Comment: Just a line curve in which y axis is count and x axis is time 0, 20, 40, 60, etc. I don't believe this needs further illustration as the requirements are clear.